# React UseState flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

in useStates, normally to set the color you would have to do setSelected(selected) to use that react hook, but it is never used like that below:  How is setSelected being used so that it can change the color?

Is onSelectedChange a function that is equal to the function setSelected?  A function receiving another function?

```
 App.js
    const options =[
        {
            label:'The color red',
            value:'red'
        },
        {
            label:'The color blue',
            value:'blue'
        },
        {
            label:'The color green',
            value:'green'
        }
    ];
    export default () => {
        const [selected, setSelected]=useState(options[0]);
        return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown 
                selected={selected}
                onSelectedChange={setSelected}
                options = {options}/>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

---

```
Dropdown.js
import React from 'react';
const Dropdown = ({options,selected, onSelectedChange})=>{
    const renderedOptions = options.map((option)=>{
        return (
            <div key = {option.value}
                className="item"
                onClick={()=>onSelectedChange(option)}
                >
                    {option.label}
            </div>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Select a color</label>
                <div className="ui selection dropdown visible active">
                    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div className="text">{selected.label}</div>
                    <div className="menu visible transition">
                        {renderedOptions}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. App.js is passing `setSelected` to Dropdown as `onSelectedChange`. Dropdown is calling it, which updates App's state. setSelected and onSelectedChange are literally the same function, just referenced by different names.

Comment: This is a classic case of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - the state isn't set in the component it's used in. You might ask why would somebody do that? Easy: separation of concerns, single responsibility principle, to make tiny, easily testable components (all of these are effectively the same thing).

Comment: Also, onClick={()=>onSelectedChange(option)} has a parameter but we didnt define onselected to have a parameter onSelectedChange={setSelected} ?

Comment: @leon - `onSelectedChange` is `setSelected`, `setSelected` is simply the dispatch returned from a `useState` hook - it's the state setter. Not sure what's confusing you here.

Comment: `() => onSelectedChange(option)` creates a _new function_ that just calls onSelectedChange (aka `setSelected`) with the current option.

Answer (score 0):

It is passed to `<Dropdown>` component as `onSelectedChange` prop

```
        <Dropdown 
            selected={selected}
            onSelectedChange={setSelected}
            options = {options}/>
```

Which is then invoked from the onClick handler `onClick={()=>onSelectedChange(option)`